# Alexandrov Topologies and Pre-Orders, equivalence relations?

Tags: general-topology

Alexandrov topologies are in bijection with pre-orders. In particular partial orders are in bijection with $T_0$ Alexandrov topologies. What about equivalence relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have an equivalence relation (as the specialisation order) then we have a partition topology: A topology so that $W(x), x \in X$ (the minimal neighbourhoods of $x$) forms a partition of $X$.

All partition topologies are Alexandrov. A $T_0$ partition topology has only singleton classes so is discrete.

Comment: So, there is a bijection between partition topologies and equivalence relations?

Comment: @TheWanderer obviously, yes.